# The proper place for non problem specific programming questions

Tags: feature-request, questions

Since the proper question guidelines have been tightened somewhat the last couple of years, I've been wondering what is the proper place to ask questions which are not focused on a particular problem, but are about how or why stuff works, for example the question on my mind is about OpenCL 2 SVM and how come there is massive speedup for non-parallel tasks considering the extra latency and interop between CPU and GPU and the fact GPU compute is in its nature intended to be massively parallel and also not nearly as wide or fast as CPUs when it comes to sequential execution.

Another topic that has been massively cracked down upon, but is in fact pretty useful to people - software / library / tool recommendation. One can even argue that it represents a specific problem - not knowing what tool to use to tackle a problem, be that because of lack of experience or a choice dilemma.

So, where does that kind of stuff go?

Bother to note this is not about "general offtopic" - it is focused on particular questions, which don't seem to fit anywhere in the existing stack exchange network. Also the question listed as a duplicate doesn't answer this question.

Comment: @jonrsharpe - more like "used to, but no longer fit", it's different from the typical offtopic. I am being fairly specific here.

Answer (score 0):

These are two questions.

Questions for recommendations can go on [Software Recommendations](http://SoftwareRecs.stackexchange.com). Do note that that site has it's own rules, people can't just go there and ask "What is the best PHP framework". They still need to be specific about their needs.

Questions about how something  works - as far as I'm concerned, a specific question about internal operation of a system should be allowed - *if* the sources for the system are available, or if there is another reason why the question can be objectively answered. Such answers help us to better understand our tools, and can teach us techniques that we may use in our own code.

If the question is "How does product ABC do XYZ, because I need to do XYZ as well" - then the question should simply be re-phrased: "I need to do XYZ. I know it's possible because product ABC does it."

Comment: Software recommendation seems like it could loosely fit, but t sorta more looks like "end user software" and less about solving a programming problem, as for the latter, I've seen a long chain of misfortune for questions  like "how and why stuff works" since those are not the typical "why doesn't this code work" or "how to do this" kind of questions. I am talking massive downvotes, hasty closings... that is just not right.